# How to temporarily backup the current folder?

Tags: bash, backup

I would like to do the following:

1. Backup the current folder
2. Run some test files
3. Restore the backup (delete all changes from previous commands)
4. Delete backup

Unfortunately I do not have Git available. Otherwise I would do

```sh
git add .
git commit -m "backup"
# run commands
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest possible way would be to just create a copy in the parent directory or other convenient location.

You could create such aliases to make it easier:

```sh
alias bak-cur-dir='(DIR="${PWD##*/}" && cd .. && cp -r "$DIR" "$DIR".bak)'
alias res-cur-dir='(DIR="${PWD##*/}" && cd .. && rm -rf "$DIR" && mv "$DIR".bak "$DIR") && cd .. && cd -'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use in such a case to create a directory `${TMP:-/tmp}/$$` for this purpose. You can later change the location, just by defining `TMP`, and it uses something reasonable, when `TMP` is unset.

```
tmpdir=${TMP:-/tmp}/$$
mkdir -p "$tmpdir"
cp -r . "$tmpdir"
.... # Do your processing and set 
.... # the variable keep_backup to
.... # your liking.
# Remove unneeded backup, when done.
if ((keep_backup == 0))
then
  rm -r "$tmpdir"
else
  echo You find a backup in $tmpdir
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /working/dir
tar cfz ../backup.tar.gz .
# do your thing
#
# and then some
rm *
tar xf ../backup.tar.gz
rm ../backup.tar.gz
```